# Nextcloud 12 password generation

Tags: php, owncloud, nextcloud

I want to generate a nextcloud password from external, where can I find which salts and encryptions are used to store the password in the database?

Answer (score 2):

the nextcloud password entry in the database is

`1|$2y$10$hDoBSweagiX8g...` (I cut it, because it's slightly longer but that isnt intresting)

I dont specifically know what the `1|` part is but `$2y$` definitely indicates a bcrypt hash with PHP's fixed behavior.

so I just tried making a quick bcrypt hash in an interactive PHP shell

`php
echo password_hash("password",PASSWORD_BCRYPT);`

and entered the new bcrypt string right after the `1|` and it worked

Answer (score 1):

To reset the password of a user you can use the `user:resetpassword` action on the `occ` command. You can find the documentation on https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/12/admin_manual/configuration_server/occ_command.html#user-commands-label.

Comment: not really helpful when you are on a plain webhoster without SSH